# Creating WebHook sender

Tags: c#, asp.net, webhooks, power-automate, asp.net-webhooks

I'm developing a Custom connector with Microsoft Flow.

I've already connected my webApp (asp.Net) with flow and it works fine!
Now I want to extend its functionalities and add some triggers through webhooks.

I followed this tutorial https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2015/09/15/sending-webhooks-with-asp-net-webhooks-preview/ but I don't know how it works with flow.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .Net Framework, you can use the Custom Sender example to get started.

https://github.com/aspnet/WebHooks/tree/78491ef819c26d85a0441a572569fa2ec96d8935/samples/CustomSender